# Decrease the waitForDelay in a SKAction loop

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can I speed up a timer in SpriteKit by 1/10 of a second each iteration?

The below code will print "Hello World" once every second, but I'm not sure how to speed it up.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
       SKAction.waitForDuration(1),
       SKAction.runBlock({ println("Hello World" })
    ])))
}
```

I can't figure out how to decrease the counter by 1/10 of a second so Hello World prints at the correct decreasing intervals.

Comment: Well what do you want to happen? It counts down tenths of a second until there is no delay and then repeats forever thereafter? I want to make sure i understand before writing the code

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what youre trying to accomplish

```
var countdown: [SKAction] = []

var delay = 1.0

let helloWorld = SKAction.runBlock({println("hello world")})

while delay > 0 {
    countdown.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(delay))
    countdown.append(helloWorld)
    delay -= 0.1
}

self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.sequence(countdown),
    SKAction.repeatActionForever(helloWorld)
]))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. At first you will print "Hello World" every second. Then next you will alternate between printing "Hello World" every second and every 9/10 of a second. Then you will just keep adding more intervals to this.  You have not sped up the timer, just added different frequencies to it.

Comment: Yes it does speed up the timer. Have you tried the code? It prints at 1 second 0.9, 0.8 and so on: eventually reaches zero and prints instantly. Isn't that what you want? My loop is creating a shorter delay

Comment: Donny, it does not alternate the way youre thinking it does.  it does exactly what youre asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement a variable time delay between print calls:

Define the time interval property

```
var interval:NSTimeInterval = 1.0
```

Add this to your `didMoveToView`

```
printHelloWorld()
```

This function creates an `SKAction` that waits for a specified amount of time and prints a string to the console. After the completion of the action, it updates the interval and then calls itself.

```
func printHelloWorld() {
    runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(self.interval),
            SKAction.runBlock({
                println("Hello World \(self.interval)")
            })
        ]),
        completion:{
            // This runs only after the previous action has completed
            self.interval -= 0.1
            if (self.interval >= 0.0) {
                self.printHelloWorld()
            }
        }
    )
}
```